# Location accuracy with 3taps API

Tags: api

I'm using the 3taps API and there's a field it returns called "accuracy", which the [documentation](http://docs.3taps.com/search_api.html) describes:

> An integer indicating the accuracy of the supplied lat/long value.

But I can't seem to find additional details.  Does accuracy mean how close the lat/long provided are to the actual location? How is this determined? What is the range and is higher better?

Sorry for so many questions, but it is really important to my use case to know whether the lat/longs are accurate.

Comment: Do you have some examples for this field? What's the range of values, and does it vary between rural/urban areas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been collecting it in my recent pulls.  The pulls come from an urban area, so I'm not really able to speak to the differences.  From other sources, I've seen accuracy = 4 and accuracy = 8, but I can't seem to find any max/min values for it.